# Weird aberration with Eevee depth of field

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

When I render my scene with eevee, I have some weird aberrations which appears on some parts of the render, like if the edge of certain objects appears while it had to be hidden by the volumetrics.
I think it's a problem of depth of field + volumetric, but I don't understand why. When I disable depth of field, the problem disapears.

Anyone have an idea ? I don't know what to do. Thanks !

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]